# Can Mercurial pull without getting bookmarks?

Tags: mercurial

Every time I pull from a repository I get not only the changesets but also all the bookmarks from that repository. In some situations this is quite annoying. Is there a way to pull without getting bookmarks?

(I'm actually using TortoiseHG, but information about plain Mercurial command line is useful and appreciated as well.)

(Background: In TortoiseHG having many bookmarks gets cluttered quickly. That doesn't matter in the remote repository where the bookmarks should remain for future reference. But locally I don't need or want them. So after each pull from the remote repository I have to delete each bookmark individually. This gets old fast...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that push copies bookmarks, so why not go to the remote repository and from there push into yours?

Alternatively, .hg/bookmarks is just a text file, what happens if you copy it, pull, and then restore the original?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to pull without getting bookmarks?

No. You get **all** remote bookmarks from remote repository every time

> In TortoiseHG having many bookmarks gets cluttered quickly

How?! Not active "external" bookmark will remain invisible in the past history quickly

but... you can rename your local, important bookmarks (give some unique prefix) and after it deleting remote bookmarks after each pull *can be* a lot easier: `grep -v PREFIX` for content of `.hg/bookmarks` file

Comment: They pollute all bookmark selection dropdowns. Some of them are not even sorted, so good luck finding and selecting that one bookmark from hundreds.

Comment: @Peter - 1) I can remember all *my* bookmarks in repo and perform `hg up BOOKNAME` in console 2) give your bookmars some special prefix (`=***`)in order to get on top of lists

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but as mentioned the bookmarks are not always sorted, so a prefix doesn't really help.