# Can Mercurial pull and replace divergent bookmarks?

Tags: mercurial

Can Mercurial pull and replace divergent bookmarks?

Background:
I have backup clones of repositories that are scheduled to pull all changes from the actual repositories.
The backup clones are never touched in any way other than that. They are cloned with `--noupdate` so the files are not even available in the working directory.

Sometimes the scheduled `hg pull` fails with an error like this:

`divergent bookmark T2029 stored as T2029@default`

I don't care about the old bookmark position. There does not seem to be anything like `hg pull --replace-divergent-bookmarks-silently`.

Alternatives:

- I would be OK with pulling all changesets, but not getting the bookmarks themselves. ([But that's apparently not possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377026/can-mercurial-pull-without-getting-bookmarks).)
- I could maybe delete all bookmarks on the backup before pulling. But there doesn't seem to be anything like  `hg bookmark -d --all` either.

Comment: That pull did not exactly fail - you have pulled all changesets successfully; it's more a warning that the bookmark (thus name attached to a specific revision) could not be properly updated, thus you now have two bookmarks.

Comment: @planetmaker Right. The problem is the presence of the error / warning on stderr makes the scheduled task fail every time.

Comment: shouldn't you rather query the process exit status than stderr output?

Comment: It's not me doing that. Also I do prefer errors to trigger failure, except if explicitly ignored.

Comment: But there's a difference between warning and error - for good reason. And that's why there is the programme's error status.

Comment: In this case there is not. And that's why it's called stderr, not stdwarn.